# Generics supports only reference conversions not boxing conversions

Tags: c#, generics, boxing, variance, unboxing

While reading **c# in a nutshell** about boxing and unboxing on page 91, author writes this:

> > Boxing conversions are crucial in providing a,unified type system. The system is not perfect, however we will see in Generics that variance with arrays and generics supports only **reference conversions ** and not **boxing conversions **

And quoted example code:

```
object [] a1 = new string [3]; //legal
object [] a2 = new int [3]; // error
```

Can somebody explain what the author is trying to deliver and why the first line is legal and second line is not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there's a *reference conversion* between `string` and `object`, in that every string reference can be treated as an object reference. This can be done transparently, with no modification to the value at all. That's why array variance can be done cheaply - for reads, anyway. Reading from an `object[]` value (as is known at compile-time) which happens to *really* be a `string[]` at execution time is basically free - you read the value, and you can treat it as an `object` reference. Writing is more painful - every write to an `object[]` has to check that the value you're writing is genuinely compatible with the array you're trying to store it in.

The important thing here is that the *representation* of a `string` reference is the same as the representation of an `object` reference.

There's a *boxing conversion* between `int` and `object` which lets this work:

```
int x = 10;
object y = x;
```

... but that conversion involves more action; the CLR has to create an object which contains the relevant integer. The representation of an `int` is *not* the same as the representation of an `object` reference. Checking whether that's necessary - and doing it as you go - would be relatively painful (from a performance perspective) when reading from an array, so it's *not* valid to treat an `int[]` as an `object[]`.

The same is true for generic variance. This is fine:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings; // IEnumerable<T> is covariant in T
```

But this isn't:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
IEnumerable<object> objects = ints; // Covariance doesn't apply here
```

For more on representation and identity, see [Eric Lippert's blog post on the topic](http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/). (It doesn't talk about variance very much, but it's all related...)

Comment: Did you mean to say,The second one won't compile ? I didn't got it well

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: If you mean the final piece of code, that's right - it won't compile.

Comment: hey @JonSkeet, how the hell are you able to elaborate such a response in 5 mins?!

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Yes, exactly. There's no conversion from `List<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: Appreciate your descriptive answer,  will read eric post as well. Thanks again